# Is a Baire $T_1$ Space, without isolated points, always uncountable?

Tags: general-topology

Is a Baire $T_1$ Space, without isolated points, always uncountable?

If "yes" then how you can prove?

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** true.

Take for instance $E=\mathbb Z$, with the metric $d(x,y)=\vert x-y\vert$.

Then $E$ is a Baire space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for Baire $T_1$ spaces without isolated points:
Otherwise $U_x = X\setminus \{x\}, x \in X$ would contradict the Baire property if $X$ were countable.

With isolated points allowed we have discrete spaces...